# What's the best way to bootstrap this header with the flex grid system?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I can get close by putting the logo, search, and text into different columns but I can't seem to find a way to move the `<nav>` into a row under the search where the logo keeps the same height as everything.

```css
#outer {}

#logo {
  padding: 1%;
  background: red;
  margin-right: 1em;
  margin-left: 1em;
}

#search_bar {
  background: green;
  padding: 0;
}

#nar_bar {
  clear: both;
}

#quote_holder {
  background: pink;
  margin-left: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="outer" class="h-100 container-fluid">

  <div class="row">

    <div id="logo" class="float-left">
      Logo,<br/> Logo,
      <br/> Logo.
    </div>

    <div id="search_bar" class="col">
      <div class="card-body row no-gutters align-items-center">
        <!--end of col-->
        <div class="col">
          <input class="form-control form-control-sm form-control-borderless" type="search" placeholder="Search topics or keywords">
        </div>
        <!--end of col-->
        <div class="col-auto">
          <button class="btn" type="submit">Search</button>
        </div>
        <!--end of col-->
      </div>

    </div>

    <div id="quote_holder" class="col align-middle">

      <p class="align-middle">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
      </p>

    </div>


  </div>

  <div id="nar_bar" class="col">

    Text Text Text Text Text Text

  </div>

</div>
```

Here's what I am looking to mimic

[image: stuck in the grid]

Comment: For better and quick response you should try putting a nicely written code. Your coedpen code seems to have been just copied and pasted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `flex` to do it. Here is an example:

```css
nav {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.logo {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}


.logo img{
  width: 100%;
}

.subcontainer {
  padding: 10px;
  background: #eee;
}

.subcontainer .searchbar,
.subcontainer .menu {
  display: block;
}

.subcontainer .searchbar {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.subcontainer .searchbar .bar {
  background: #999;
  height: 20px;
  width: 70%;
}

.subcontainer .searchbar button {
  width: 25%;
}

.subcontainer .menu ul{
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0;
}

.subcontainer .menu ul li{
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.text {
  background: #eee;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.text p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav>
  <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="logo col-2 col-sm-2 col-md-1">
      <img src="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/assets/brand/bootstrap-solid.svg">
    </div>
    <div class="subcontainer col-10 col-sm-10 col-md-5">
      <div class="searchbar">
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <button>Search</button>
      </div>
      <div class="menu">
        <ul>
          <li>Home</li>
          <li>About</li>
          <li>Projects</li>
          <li>Contact</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="text col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In varius semper eleifend.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Wow, this is awesome, thank you. How long have you been working with bootstrap to know this? I'm surprised it needs as much CSS as it does.

I've never really seen subcontainer in use before.

Comment: Thanks @IanSmith! With practice you'll also be able to do things like this even more ;)